# python asyncio queue crash

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

i'm developing with python asyncio queue, in the following code, it deals with queue and workers in async, creating workers and update a field in DB.

Eventually some worker stop and script "freeze" at all, needing "CTRL+C".

Someone knows how to deal with it? how to kill worker in crash case? or set timeout to kill worker and continue running the script?

Here's the code:

```
async def updateDatabase():

    #database update
 
    #await function()

async def worker(name, queue):
    
    while True:
    
    
        updatedb = await queue.get()
    
        await updatedb()

        queue.task_done()
        print("DB updated ", name, "\n")

    async def main():
    
    
        queue = asyncio.Queue()
    
    
    
        for _ in range(100000):
    
            queue.put_nowait(updateDatabase)


    # Create three worker tasks to process the queue concurrently.
    tasks = []
    for i in range(300):
        task = asyncio.create_task( worker(f'worker-{i}', queue)) 
        tasks.append(task)





    # Wait until the queue is fully processed.

    await queue.join()                                                 




    # Cancel our worker tasks.                                             
    for task in tasks:
        task.cancel()

    # Wait until all worker tasks are cancelled.

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)    

    print('====')

if __name__ == '__main__':


    start = timer()

    asyncio.run(main())

    end = timer()

    print(end-start)
```

Here is the Traceback:

```
^A^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "quesync2.py", line 112, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 570, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1823, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/selectors.py", line 468, in select
    fd_event_list = self._selector.poll(timeout, max_ev)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code. I suspect that it doesn't always reflect the indentation of your actual code. And you have a syntax error because of it.

Comment: Don't reflect... just paste issue =)